# 2012 Macbook Pro second SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, diskutil

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro with a 500GB Samsung SSD running Mojave. I  replaced the optical drive with a hard drive and everything worked fine.

Recently, I replaced the old hard drive in the optical bay with a new HP 128GB SSD. With the HDD, my boot time was around 14 seconds. Now, with the SSD, it hangs for a second and then opens Disk Utility. I tried to click anything in Disk Utility and it continues to hang again.

I am about to pull it apart in frustration and format the darn thing with my clone cable. What could be causing the hanging and how should I format it if I am only storing code?

Answer (score 1):

The "hang" is most likely caused by the HP SSD being pre-formatted for Windows computers (NTFS) which macOS cannot read by default.  If you wipe the drive with a macOS compatible format, it will likely fix the issue.

Using Terminal, issue the following command:

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ Untitled GPT /dev/diskX
```

- `HFS+` is the format of the new drive
- `Untitled` is the name of the new drive
- `GPT` is the partition scheme
- `/dev/diskX` is the drive identifier (use `diskutil list` to obtain identifier)

Comment: Sorry for the long no-show. Turns out the SSD was no good. I went with Samsung and works great